# display block not working Razor in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 for loops in Razor syntax , I want to implement each one in a block , I added style block to second for loop but it appears inline with the first line of contents to the first loop

```
<div style="display:block;">
    @foreach (var Item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>@Item.Name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <br>
</div>

// the page buttons appear next to @Item.Name (at the first line of the loop items) not after it
<div style="display:block;">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.TotalPages; i++)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="addressSearch" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("myaction","mycontroller", new { page = i } )'">@i</button>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: The default for a `<div>` is `block` so adding it not necessary. Its not clear what your trying to achieve or what problems your having (perhaps include an image of what your getting and what you want)

Comment: put an empty row for a quick fix <div class=row></div>

Comment: thanks  RAHUL S R is working with your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work if it is not !important in external stylesheet